# How to add full desktop & configs to a minimal install?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-minimal

all -

Brand new to anything non-Windows, allured by ZFS and Ubuntu to set up a large storage pool at home on a functional desktop.

I have an AMD64 Ubuntu 12.04.2 [debootstrap minimal install on a ZFS root](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem), which gives me a command prompt OS that isn't very familiar with my system hardware, and I don't know where to go from here. I assume the Desktop installation CD is a no-go, since it's not likely to understand the ZFS filesystem well. What's my road map for putting on the full GUI (with multiple users, CUPS, Samba file shares with Windows & Mac things, media serving, etc.) and getting all the devices working and settings configured?

Is it as simple as "apt-get install ubuntu-desktop"? Will that get things all plugged in & working? Or will I have to manually configure things before/during/after the installation?

Or will the Alternate CD be able to work with a pre-existing OS and continue a semi-automatic installation?

Or should I try to get all UNIXy and get the minimal system more configured, adding the desktop afterwards?

Thanks much!

Comment: Yes.  It is that simple.

Comment: Thanks! Will apt-get be smart enough to check to see if the files it needs are on the CD, or is this 100% downloaded stuff?

Comment: Use the search function at the top right to find out how to add a disk as a software repo

Comment: Got it elsewhere:  "apt-cdrom add" followed by "apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" seems to be doing things quickly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use tasksel for this!

Just install it via

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

run it with

```
sudo tasksel
```

and then you can select a bunch of packages to install inlcluding Ubuntu-Desktop or even Lubuntu...

Comment: Thanks for the help, will kick it a bit and see how it turns out.